# Why NPM is working locally but not on Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, proxy

I'm on Windows 10

I'm on a new project and I can't use `npm install` and `npm audit fix` on `docker-compose up -d`, so it's stuck on the first npm install

NPM is working locally with my configured proxy :

`npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

I tried to configure docker proxy, windows proxy and npm proxy, and to npm install manually folder and it's working without docker

I tried on Linux and on other computer too, and it's not working too

Node version is : v10.15.0

Npm version is : 6.9.0

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cors failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ip.ip.ip.ip:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:196:13)
...
```

I can provide the full error

I think it's a proxy problem but I can't understand why and how I can try something else

On another network I can `docker-compose up -d` without any problems

E: I tried without results :

`ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://proxy.company.com:8080"`

and configure `.docker/config.json`

Comment: Can you contact the outside world (e.g.: ping/curl) from a docker container?

Comment: No, I can't ping registry.npmjs.org on Docker and locally, it's blocked by sys admin I guess, I just can't ping on Windows Command Prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to configure container proxy with a JSON file `/.docker/config.json` like :

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://username:password@PROXY_IP:port",
     "httpsProxy": "http://username:password@PROXY_IP:port",
     "noProxy": "noproxiesinformation"
   }
 }
}
```

So configure Docker proxy and Docker container proxy and it's working

Answer (score 5):

```
http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

could not resolved by your docker network.you should run your docker with the same network interface as your host machine
by passing `--network host` to your docker run command

Comment: I'm trying to do that but I'm not sure how to add this to my docker-compose file

Comment: Thanks, I change the version to 3.4, and added network: host in my docker-compose file builds but still nothing

Comment: How I can know if docker using the host network on compose ? To be sure it's ok with params ?